# R purrr row-wise lookups from two lists

Tags: r, purrr

Here’s a simplified version of a problem that involves larger, more complex inputs. First, I create data:

```
input <- tibble(
  person = rep(101:103, each = 12),
  item = rep(1:12, 3),
  response = sample(1:4, 36, replace = T)
)
```

These data are responses from three persons on a 12-item test. `input` is a multilevel table in which the test items are nested within each person. The columns of `input` are:

- `person`: ID numbers for persons `101`, `102`, and `103` (12 rows for each person)
- `item`: test items 1-12 for each person. Note how the items are nested within each person
- `response`: score for each item

The test is divided into four subscales consisting of three items each.

```
scale_assign <- list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:12)
scale_num <- 1:4
```

`scale_assign` is a four-element list containing four item sets (expressed as four numerical ranges): items 1-3 (subscale 1), items 4-6 (subscale 2), items 7-9 (subscale 3), and items 10-12 (subscale 4).  `scale_num` is a four element numerical vector containing the numbers (1-4) that label the four subscales.

What I want R to do is process `input` row-wise, creating a new column `scale`, and filling it with the correct value of `scale_num` for each item (that is, each item's subscale assignment). In each row, R needs to check the value of `item` against the ranges in `scale_assign` and fill in `scale` with the value of `scale_num` that corresponds to the `scale_assign` range for that item.

The desired output looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 36 x 4
#      person  item response scale
#  1    101     1        4     1
#  2    101     2        2     1
#  3    101     3        4     1
#  4    101     4        4     2
#  5    101     5        4     2
#  6    101     6        4     2
#  7    101     7        3     3
#  8    101     8        2     3
#  9    101     9        4     3
# 10    101    10        1     4
# 11    101    11        1     4
# 12    101    12        4     4
# 13    102     1        1     1
# 14    102     2        3     1
# 15    102     3        1     1
# 16    102     4        1     2
# 17    102     5        3     2
# 18    102     6        3     2
# 19    102     7        4     3
# 20    102     8        1     3
# 21    102     9        3     3
# 22    102    10        4     4
# 23    102    11        3     4
# 24    102    12        3     4
# 25    103     1        4     1
# 26    103     2        1     1
# 27    103     3        2     1
# 28    103     4        2     2
# 29    103     5        4     2
# 30    103     6        1     2
# 31    103     7        4     3
# 32    103     8        4     3
# 33    103     9        1     3
# 34    103    10        4     4
# 35    103    11        1     4
# 36    103    12        2     4
```

Preferring a `tidyverse` solution, I thought this might be a job for `purrr::map2()`, because it seems to involve simultaneous iteration over a four-element list `scale_assign` and a four-element vector `scale_num`. I tried to implement the coding of `scale` within a `map2()` call, using `mutate()` and `case_when()` to do the coding, but could not get it to work.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Since this is just consecutive numeric ranges (assuming the example is representative), you could also use something like `findInterval` - `scale_num[findInterval(input$item, sapply(scale_assign, min))]` . The join is a fair more adaptable solution however.

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of performing this operation row-wise and checking for each value it would be easy to perform a join operation if you change `scale_assign` to named list convert it into a dataframe and do a `right_join` with `input` dataframe.

```
scale_assign <- list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:12)
names(scale_assign) <- 1:4

library(tidyverse)

enframe(scale_assign) %>%
   unnest(cols = value) %>%
   mutate_all(as.integer) %>%
   right_join(input, by = c("value" = "item"))


# A tibble: 36 x 4
#    name value person response
#   <int> <int>  <int>    <int>
# 1     1     1    101        4
# 2     1     2    101        4
# 3     1     3    101        2
# 4     2     4    101        2
# 5     2     5    101        1
# 6     2     6    101        4
# 7     3     7    101        3
# 8     3     8    101        1
# 9     3     9    101        1
#10     4    10    101        2
# … with 26 more rows
```

---

In base R, that can be done using `stack` and `merge`

```
merge(input, stack(scale_assign), all.x = TRUE, by.x = "item", by.y = "values")
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
input <- tibble(
   person = rep(101:103, each = 12),
   item = rep(1:12, 3),
   response = sample(1:4, 36, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: It'll also be orders of magnitude quicker than looping every row.

Comment: Thank you - shortly after posting my question, I realized that the problem becomes much easier if the lookup information is in a table that can be joined, as opposed to doing row-wise processing. Your answer works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` solution, using an update-join.
Basically this is @Ronak Shah's Base-R answer, but using the `data.table`-package (i.e. fast performance on large data-sets).

```
library(data.table)
#1. set inpus as data.table
#2. create a lookup-table using `stack( scale_assign )`, 
#  and make that also a data.table (using setDT() )
#3. left update join on item
setDT(input)[ setDT( stack( scale_assign ) ), 
                     scale := i.ind,
                     on = .( item = values ) ][]
```

**output**

```
#     person item response scale
#  1:    101    1        3     1
#  2:    101    2        4     1
#  3:    101    3        3     1
#  4:    101    4        2     2
#  5:    101    5        3     2
#  6:    101    6        4     2
#  7:    101    7        1     3
#  8:    101    8        3     3
#  9:    101    9        4     3
# 10:    101   10        2     4
# 11:    101   11        3     4
# 12:    101   12        4     4
# 13:    102    1        4     1
# 14:    102    2        2     1
# 15:    102    3        3     1
# 16:    102    4        2     2
# 17:    102    5        1     2
# 18:    102    6        4     2
# 19:    102    7        1     3
# 20:    102    8        3     3
# 21:    102    9        2     3
# 22:    102   10        1     4
# 23:    102   11        4     4
# 24:    102   12        3     4
# 25:    103    1        1     1
# 26:    103    2        1     1
# 27:    103    3        2     1
# 28:    103    4        1     2
# 29:    103    5        2     2
# 30:    103    6        4     2
# 31:    103    7        4     3
# 32:    103    8        2     3
# 33:    103    9        3     3
# 34:    103   10        2     4
# 35:    103   11        2     4
# 36:    103   12        2     4
#     person item response scale
```

Comment: thank you for this, I need to get more familiar with `data.table`.